# column "distance" does not exist

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query that finds the places near my location, but every time I try to run it, it returns the following error:

> column "distance" does not exist

If I remove distance and only leave up to the `FROM posts`, it returns the post id and the distance column.

But if I leave it in the original way, it returns the error.

```
SELECT id, 
       ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-32.63) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
       cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-71.42) ) + sin( radians(-32.63) ) * 
       sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM posts 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: When asking a SQL question, it is almost always necessary to add a tag for the RDBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax differs greatly between them. Adding that tag both helps to get you an answer faster and avoids wasting the time of people who take the time to write an answer only to find out it won't work in the specific RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in other places in the same query. You'll have to either repeat the entire expression in your HAVING and ORDER BY or use your existing query as a sub-query and apply the HAVING and ORDER BY to the outer query, or use a CTE if your RDBMS supports it.

```
SELECT id, distance FROM 
  (SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-32.63) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
   cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-71.42) ) + sin( radians(-32.63) ) * 
   sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM posts) p 
WHERE distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: Using a subquery, you should replace `HAVING` with `WHERE`.

Comment: @treuss: Yes, you're right. I was paying more attention to solving the OP's immediate problem instead of the overall statement. Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put CTA to order it by distance